# How to measure how much time does it take for a SSR Next server to send back the HTML and why?

Tags: node.js, performance, next.js, profiling, server-side-rendering

Currently I have a Next application with SSR using getInitialProps that takes too long to deliver the HTML based on the complexity of the app (I'm getting high `Waiting for Server` to respond times in Chrome in the network tab).

I'd want to figure out what is adding so much time (sometimes I get seconds), so I'm trying to:F

1. Find out how much time does it take for the server from the time it receives the GET request for the page to the time it sends the HTML
2. Have a clear picture of what's happening and how much time does it take during the SSR. Because at the moment is a black box for me.

I tried suggested improvements: code splitting, lazy loading components, code improvements, etc.

I tried using [Server Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Server-Timing) to measure the requests performed in getInitialProps, to narrow down a part of the process. But it doens't help with the rendering process and other Next processes that might add to the response time.

I tried using the Node.js profiler for Chrome using `NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' next dev`. This is the closest I got to what I wanted, but I can't tell where does the server respond back, and what do each Activity corresponds to. Some documentation could be helpful.

I tried middleware. Not sure if I got something wrong, but I can't measure the time from start to finish.

Some observations were that other more simple pages, have faster response times, but regardless the time it takes is extremely longer (1 - 2 orders of magnitude)